# Mock a method returning an interface with NInject Mocking Kernel

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, ninject-mockingkernel

Say I  have an interface like this.

```
public interface ICamProcRepository
{
    List<IAitoeRedCell> GetAllAitoeRedCells();
    IAitoeRedCell CreateAitoeRedCell();
}
```

How do I mock the method which return an interface and a list of interface objects. I am using Ninject.MockingKernel.Moq

```
var mockingKernel = new MoqMockingKernel();

var camProcRepositoryMock = mockingKernel.GetMock<ICamProcRepository>();

camProcRepositoryMock.Setup(e => e.GetAllAitoeRedCells()).Returns(?????WHAT HERE?????);

camProcRepositoryMock.Setup(e => e.CreateAitoeRedCell()).Returns(?????WHAT HERE?????);
```

Comment: by creating mocks of the desired results and passing them to the `Returns` of the setup. either via kernel or straight moq. I don't know Ninject to be able to help you there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you need to create mocks of the desired results for the mocked interface in question and pass them into the `Returns` of its setups, either via kernel or straight moq. I don't know Ninject to be able to help you there but here is a plain Moq example

```
var mockingKernel = new MoqMockingKernel();

var camProcRepositoryMock = mockingKernel.GetMock<ICamProcRepository>();

var fakeList = new List<IAitoeRedCell>();
//You can either leave the list empty or populate it with mocks.
//for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
//    fakeList.Add(Mock.Of<IAitoeRedCell>());
//}

camProcRepositoryMock.Setup(e => e.GetAllAitoeRedCells()).Returns(fakeList);

camProcRepositoryMock.Setup(e => e.CreateAitoeRedCell()).Returns(() => Mock.Of<IAitoeRedCell>());
```

If the mocked objects need to provide fake functionality as well then the too will have to be setup accordingly.

Comment: OK, makes sense. Let me give it a try.